# Как избежать пустого ответа на запрос access?

Tags: access

Есть запрос на выорку в Access. Ввожу условие, таких данных в тблице нет, выводится пустой ответ(пустая трока). Как вывести например msgBox с фразой "ничего не найдено" или что-то в этом духе?

Comment: На бейсике надо открывать запрос (с тем же sql что и сейчас, но предварительно проверять count и соответствующий MsgBox если 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если этот запрос используется как источник данных для формы, то можно узнать количество записей так:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.Recordset
... = rst.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

adotable.recordcount() == 0 ...

Comment: судя по тегу и msgBox его не интересует доступ извне к аксесной базе, а чистый аксесс